# gpg2 is unaware of secret and public key on smartcard

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I set up a new platform with gpg2 and smartcardsupport. But now I cannot encrypt and decrypt with my keys on smartcard. Before my setup asked for encryption the receiver email address and with inserted smartcard I entered my PIN.

Now my email address is unknown to gpg2 for encryption to myself.

How do I make my new platform aware of the keys again?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Enigmail now finds the keys, after accessing the smartcard info and importing the public key from keyserver.

Comment: New platform again and enigmail public key import from keyserver does not work... very buggy!

Answer (score 0):

it should suffice to have the Smartcard's Public Key in `keyring.pgp` or similar file name on local machine:

- Export Public Key from Smartcard with gpg2, or
- import public key from keyserver, must have been exported previously with gpg2